# Validate user input car registration access 2010 webform

Tags: validation, webforms, ms-access-2010, user-input

I am trying to validate the user input into a text box on a web form in Access 2010. the format that i'm trying to verify is for Rep. Ireland car registrations and so should be in the format:

Field format is to be YYY-CC-SSSSSS:-
YYY – 3-digit year format starting in 2013 (YY – 2-digit year format from 1997 to 2012) so can be either YY or YYY
CC – a 1 or 2-character County/City identifier (A-Z)
SSSSSS – a 1 to 6-digit sequence number

I have tried using input masks but not sure on the best way to do this due to the various combinations that are possible. I also thought on using a regex expression but this is not available to use in access 2010.

Any pointers / advise would be greatful

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using this as the `Validation Rule` for that field in the table

```
Like "##-?-#" Or Like "##-?-##" Or Like "##-?-###" Or Like "##-?-####" Or Like "##-?-#####" Or Like "##-?-######" Or Like "##-??-#" Or Like "##-??-##" Or Like "##-??-###" Or Like "##-??-####" Or Like "##-??-#####" Or Like "##-??-######" Or Like "###-?-#" Or Like "###-?-##" Or Like "###-?-###" Or Like "###-?-####" Or Like "###-?-#####" Or Like "###-?-######" Or Like "###-??-#" Or Like "###-??-##" Or Like "###-??-###" Or Like "###-??-####" Or Like "###-??-#####" Or Like "###-??-######"
```

It may not be bulletproof but it might help.